# How to get the list of files open in active eclipse editor window in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Interest is to get list of opened files in eclipse cdt editor.
Lets say aaa.c, bbb.c, ddd.c are the files opened in eclipse editor. How to get the IFile[] for these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of all open editors using the `IWorkbenchPage` `getEditorReferences` method. You can use this to find the editors you are interested in. So:

```java
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IEditorReference [] editors = page.getEditorReferences();

for (IEditorReference editor : editors) {
  String editorId = editor.getId();

  // TODO test if this is an editor you are interested in

  IEditorInput inout = editor.getEditorInput();

  IFile file = inout.getAdapter(IFile.class);

  ...
}
```